# following toggle/poptext doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

i've created a poptext/toggle menu. All data were retrieved from the database table "jobshiring" with 2 columns which is 'job' & 'description'. the 1st data displayed on the page works fine. Example: Job1 (when clicked, the description will appear). but the following jobs aside from Job1 isn't clickable , in short, toggle function doesn't work. i tried fixing the script but i don't have that much knowledge in javascript. what part do i need to fix? :(

```
CSS:

   #toggle {
   position: relative;
   bottom: 0px;
   width: 240px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-bottom: 10px;

}
#box {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
  background-color: #644d52;
  display: none;
  opacity: .9;
  width: 100%;

}
#box p {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 5px 20px 15px 20px;
 text-align: left;
 color: #FFF;
}
#poptext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 23px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
 }
#poptext.highlight {
  background: brown;
 }
```

HTML/PHP/SCRIPT:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script> 
    document.write('<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></' + 'script>');
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    $('#poptext').click(function() {
    $('#poptext').toggleClass('highlight');
    $('#box').animate({
         height: 'toggle',
         opacity: 'toggle',
         width: 'toggle'
         }, 500);
      });
   })
</script>


<body>


<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM jobshiring");

                    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                    $job = $row['job'];
                    $description = $row['description'];

?>
    <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext"><?php echo $job; ?></div>
        <div id="box">
            <p> <?php echo $description ?>  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>


PAGE SOURCE:
    <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext">Web Developer</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et tempus arcu, ac ultrices enim. Etiam dapibus ante at feugiat condimentum. Integer ut varius turpis. Quisque lacus tortor, consequat eu ante in, pharetra lobortis ipsum. Mauris quis lectus maximus, sollicitudin odio non, posuere nisl. Nunc hendrerit lectus sed mauris aliquet, ut porttitor odio euismod. Praesent ut felis facilisis odio laoreet vulputate at eget sem. Nullam ut purus at justo pulvinar molestie. Suspendisse et massa sed ex sodales efficitur. Nam rutrum sem justo, non facilisis turpis maximus at. Sed tincidunt nibh vel dolor imperdiet, nec sollicitudin dolor auctor. Suspendisse pharetra sem tellus, et rutrum massa scelerisque non. Pellentesque luctus quam libero. Maecenas suscipit sem eu urna ornare tristique.  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext">Systems Analyst</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et tempus arcu, ac ultrices enim. Etiam dapibus ante at feugiat condimentum. Integer ut varius turpis. Quisque lacus tortor, consequat eu ante in, pharetra lobortis ipsum. Mauris quis lectus maximus, sollicitudin odio non, posuere nisl. Nunc hendrerit lectus sed mauris aliquet, ut porttitor odio euismod. Praesent ut felis facilisis odio laoreet vulputate at eget sem. Nullam ut purus at justo pulvinar molestie. Suspendisse et massa sed ex sodales efficitur. Nam rutrum sem justo, non facilisis turpis maximus at. Sed tincidunt nibh vel dolor imperdiet, nec sollicitudin dolor auctor. Suspendisse pharetra sem tellus, et rutrum massa scelerisque non. Pellentesque luctus quam libero. Maecenas suscipit sem eu urna ornare tristique.  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext">Business Analysts</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>       Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce et tempus arcu, ac ultrices enim. Etiam dapibus ante at feugiat condimentum. Integer ut varius turpis. Quisque lacus tortor, consequat eu ante in, pharetra lobortis ipsum. Mauris quis lectus maximus, sollicitudin odio non, posuere nisl. Nunc hendrerit lectus sed mauris aliquet, ut porttitor odio euismod. Praesent ut felis facilisis odio laoreet vulputate at eget sem. Nullam ut purus at justo pulvinar molestie. Suspendisse et massa sed ex sodales efficitur. Nam rutrum sem justo, non facilisis turpis maximus at. Sed tincidunt nibh vel dolor imperdiet, nec sollicitudin dolor auctor. Suspendisse pharetra sem tellus, et rutrum massa scelerisque non. Pellentesque luctus quam libero. Maecenas suscipit sem eu urna ornare tristique.     </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext">asdasf</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>      asfsaf  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
            <div id="toggle">
      <div id="poptext">asda</div>
        <div id="box">
            <p>        sasdsa asdas  </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: why do you have 3 different versions of jQuery

Comment: ID of an element must be unique.. use class instead

Comment: where can i get the generated html? and anyway, you're also the one who helped me with this issue awhile ago. i added some code so that the data will come from database. hope you could help me with this one too. what do i need to remove on my jqueries?

Comment: poptext? should i make it .poptext and .poptext.highlight?

Comment: from browser > view source

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/u9L0rxk9/3/

Comment: ok kindly check it. i added the html from my browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106328/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-gracia).

Comment: ya that works, but my code is under loop in php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have so many different versions of jQuery, just have the latest one

ID of an element must be unique, if you want to group multiple elements using a common attribute use a common class instead of ID. The ID selector will fetch only the first element with the given ID, that is why in your case only the first one is working.

Also inside the event handler, you need to work on elements which are related to the clicked element, so you can use `this` inside the handler to refer to the clicked `poptext` element and toggle its class, then use the same reference to find the `box` element as given below

So

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.poptext').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('highlight');
    $(this).next('.box').animate({
      height: 'toggle',
      opacity: 'toggle',
      width: 'toggle'
    }, 500);
  });
})
```

```css
.toggle {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 240px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.box {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px #000;
  background-color: #644d52;
  display: none;
  opacity: .9;
  width: 100%;
}
.box p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 20px 15px 20px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF;
}
.poptext {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 23px;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
.poptext.highlight {
  background: brown;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="poptext">text 1</div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>box 1</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="poptext">text 2</div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>box 2</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="toggle">
  <div class="poptext">text 3</div>
  <div class="box">
    <p>box 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```